# Comparing two fields in the same collections

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection in Mongo.

I have two fields : checksum and checksumN-4.

I already make a filter like this :

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("metadata.origin", sOrigin.ToString())
               & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("metadata.transfered", BsonNull.Value)
              & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("metadata.duplicate", BsonNull.Value)
             & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("metadata.malformed", BsonNull.Value);
```

I want to have only the document which the fields checksum and checksumN-4 are differents.

For example :

```
Cheksum : 2222222
checksumN-4 : 2222222
```

I want this record

```
Checksum : 8888888
ChecksumN-4 : 8889998
```

I don't want this record

How can I do that in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating `BsonDocumentFilterDefinition` with an expression like below :

```
 var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
 var filter = builder.Eq("metadata.origin", sOrigin.ToString())
              & builder.Eq("metadata.transfered", BsonNull.Value)
              & builder.Eq("metadata.duplicate", BsonNull.Value)
              & builder.Eq("metadata.malformed", BsonNull.Value)
              & new BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument(
                    "$expr", new BsonDocument(
                        "$eq", new BsonArray
                        {
                            "$checksumN-4", "$checksum"
                        })));
```

Comment: @LinedaChouaki Please mark as answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need mongoDb Expr for this.

First add your project such as:

```
var pro = new BsonDocument {
            {"ne1", new BsonDocument {
                { "$ne", new BsonArray(){ "$Cheksum", "$ChecksumN-4" }
                }
            } },
            {"other variables", true }
            };
```

Now you need to implement this expression and we need to make a filter for it.

```
var myfilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("ne1", true);
```

You need to merge both you filter such as:

```
var ndFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(yourFilter, myfilter);
```

You need put this filter and project in your aggregate and it will not return values which are not same.
Now our query is ready. We can check our query as follow:

```
var query=aggregate.ToString();
```

Lets run our query as follow:

```
var query=aggregate.ToList();
```

This with return the required data in list of bson documents.

This solution will work mongo c# driver 3.6 or above. Please comment in case of any confusion. Hopefully i'll able to explain this.